# My form is not submitting and I get no error at all

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-form

I am working on a project with Laravel 5.2. I am not getting any error whatsoever and my form isnt submitting as well.

heres my form

```html
<form class="form-horizontal">
                    {!! Form::open(['method'=>'POST','action'=>'TicketsController@store','files'=>true],['class=>form-horizontal form bordered']) !!}

                    <div class="form-group">
                        {!! Form::label('problem_title','title',['class'=>'control-label col-lg-2']) !!}
                        <div class="col-lg-10">{!! Form::text('problem_title',null,['class'=>'form-control']) !!}</div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group ">
                        {!! Form::label('category_id','Category:',['class'=>'control-label col-lg-2']) !!}
                        <div class="col-lg-10">{!! Form::select('category_id',$categories,'3',['class'=>'form-control']) !!}</div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group ">
                        {!! Form::label('Status_id','Status:',['class'=>'control-label col-lg-2']) !!}
                        <div class="col-lg-10">{!! Form::select('status_id',$statuses,'3',['class'=>'form-control']) !!}</div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        {!! Form::label('body','How can We help you?',['class'=>'control-label col-lg-2']) !!}
                        <div class="col-lg-10">{!! Form::text('body',null,['class'=>'form-control','rows'=>5 ,'cols'=>5]) !!}</div>

                    </div>


                    <div class="form-group">
                        {!! Form::label('photo_id','ScreenShot:',['class'=>'control-label col-lg-2']) !!}
                        <div class="col-lg-10">{!! Form::file('photo_id', ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}</div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="text-right">

                        {!! Form::submit('Create Ticket',['class'=>'btn btn-primary ']) !!}

                    </div>

                </form>
```

Also this is my controller to create and store the form.

```html
 public function create()
    {
      $categories=Category::lists('name','id')->all();
      $statuses=Status::lists('name','id')->all();
      return view('tickets.create', compact('categories','statuses','users'));
    }
    
    
    
     public function store(Request $request)
    {
        {
            $user=Auth::user();
            $input = $request->all();
            if($file=$request->file('photo_id')){
                $name=time() . $file->getClientOriginalName();
                $file-> move('images',$name);
                $photo=Photo::create(['file'=>$name]);
                $input['photo_id']=$photo->id;
            }

            $user->ticket()->create($input);
            /*Post::create($input);*/
            return redirect('tickets');
        }
    }
```

What am I doing wrong? I am getting this in my URL after I have submitted the form. Kidly help out, I am running out of time.

```html
http://www.projecty.com/tickets/create?_token=eXQHc1FS8mObR4lbyqxvXlASyZfZNidVgnjacaSb&_token=eXQHc1FS8mObR4lbyqxvXlASyZfZNidVgnjacaSb&problem_title=chuu&category_id=2&status_id=1&body=h7ju87&photo_id=house.jpg
```

Comment: you have the route setup properly?

Comment: yes I am using a resource controller, therefore all my route are handled by it.

Comment: What about those double brackets in `store()`?

Comment: @kerbholz u mean?

Comment: The double brackets: `public function store(Request $request)
    {
        {`

Comment: just remove two of them and I still get the same result

Answer (score 1):

I don't have more experience with laravel but in 2nd line you have written `['class=>form-horizontal form bordered']` and everywhere else you have `['class'=>'form-control']`. do error-reporting ON and debug your code which line is trouble you.

Comment: You are right @softech I mixed up the classes, I even attached two forms within themselves. Through your suggestion,  I was able to solve the problem. Thanks.